# Is my query correct ? And exists or not a website which can check my queries?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a data only if it doesnt already exists. heres how i do :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Nom, IDSociete FROM stagiaire, societe WHERE Nom = 'Paul' AND IDSociete = (SELECT ID from soceite where NomSoc='Promoplantes')) 
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO stagiaire(Nom, Email, Telephone, IDSociete, Pseudo, Password) 
            VALUES('Paul', 'paul@mail.com', 
            '000000000', '2'
            , 'paulPseudo', 'paulPassword')
            END
```

And it wont works.
I have :
Paul who work for Promoplantes
I want :
Paul who work for KebabHouse
(this is an example)
My query just see there is already a Paul so it doesnt insert it. But they are different Paul's !
Do you have any idea where is my failure ?

Also, do you know any website which can check my queries syntax in the future ?

Comment: you've got `SELCT` not `SELECT`

Comment: Yeah i saw and correct that. i forgot to changed it here.

Comment: Are you sure your table name is correct also 'soceite'?

Comment: That i havent saw ! but it still dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. It should remove the need for to use the sub-query by replacing it with a join (more efficient)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM stagiaire stg
    LEFT JOIN societe sct
    ON stg.IDSociete = sct.ID
    WHERE Nom = 'Paul' 
    AND NomSoc = 'Promoplantes'
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stagiarie (Nom, Email, Telephone, IDScoiete, Pseudo, Password)
    VALUES ('Paul', 'paul@mail.com', '000000000', '2', 'paulPseudo', 'paulPassword')
END
```

Comment: Have you checked it definitely doesn't exist in the tables?

Comment: Yes. In my table i have a Paul who work at promoplantes. When i change promoplantes value in my query, it doesnt me a new paul.

Comment: What does the `SELECT` query return when you have change promoplantes value?

Comment: Can you upload a sample of your data to here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Nothing. Thats logic because paul (the first) is bind to promoplantes.